# OutofMemoryError When playing GIF File in android

Tags: android

I want to play gif file in android on imageview. I used this link http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/ . This works fine but when I am using two buttons and I am swaping the gif images continuously app crashed after sometime..

This is my code

```
public class GifDecoder {
        public static final int STATUS_OK = 0;
        public static final int STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR = 1;
        /**
         * File read status: Unable to open source.
         */
        public static final int STATUS_OPEN_ERROR = 2;
        /** max decoder pixel stack size */
        protected static final int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 4096;
        protected InputStream in;
        protected int status;
        protected int width; // full image width
        protected int height; // full image height
        protected boolean gctFlag; // global color table used
        protected int gctSize; // size of global color table
        protected int loopCount = 1; // iterations; 0 = repeat forever
        protected int[] gct; // global color table
        protected int[] lct; // local color table
        protected int[] act; // active color table
        protected int bgIndex; // background color index
        protected int bgColor; // background color
        protected int lastBgColor; // previous bg color
        protected int pixelAspect; // pixel aspect ratio
        protected boolean lctFlag; // local color table flag
        protected boolean interlace; // interlace flag
        protected int lctSize; // local color table size
        protected int ix, iy, iw, ih; // current image rectangle
        protected int lrx, lry, lrw, lrh;
        protected Bitmap image; // current frame
        protected Bitmap lastBitmap; // previous frame
        protected byte[] block = new byte[256]; // current data block
        protected int blockSize = 0; // block size last graphic control extension info
        protected int dispose = 0; // 0=no action; 1=leave in place; 2=restore to bg; 3=restore to prev
        protected int lastDispose = 0;
        protected boolean transparency = false; // use transparent color
        protected int delay = 0; // delay in milliseconds
        protected int transIndex; // transparent color index
        // LZW decoder working arrays
        protected short[] prefix;
        protected byte[] suffix;
        protected byte[] pixelStack;
        protected byte[] pixels;
        protected Vector<GifFrame> frames; // frames read from current file
        protected int frameCount;

        private static class GifFrame {
                public GifFrame(Bitmap im, int del) {
                        image = im;
                        delay = del;
                }

                public Bitmap image;
                public int delay;
        }

        /**
         * Gets display duration for specified frame.
         * 
         * @param n
         *          int index of frame
         * @return delay in milliseconds
         */
        public int getDelay(int n) {
                delay = -1;
                if ((n >= 0) && (n < frameCount)) {
                        delay = frames.elementAt(n).delay;
                }
                return delay;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the number of frames read from file.
         * 
         * @return frame count
         */
        public int getFrameCount() {
                return frameCount;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
                return getFrame(0);
        }

        public int getLoopCount() {
                return loopCount;
        }

        protected void setPixels() {
                // expose destination image's pixels as int array
                int[] dest = new int[width * height];
                // fill in starting image contents based on last image's dispose code
                if (lastDispose > 0) {
                        if (lastDispose == 3) {
                                // use image before last
                                int n = frameCount - 2;
                                if (n > 0) {
                                        lastBitmap = getFrame(n - 1);
                                } else {
                                        lastBitmap = null;
                                }
                        }
                        if (lastBitmap != null) {
                                lastBitmap.getPixels(dest, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
                                // copy pixels
                                if (lastDispose == 2) {
                                        // fill last image rect area with background color
                                        int c = 0;
                                        if (!transparency) {
                                                c = lastBgColor;
                                        }
                                        for (int i = 0; i < lrh; i++) {
                                                int n1 = (lry + i) * width + lrx;
                                                int n2 = n1 + lrw;
                                                for (int k = n1; k < n2; k++) {
                                                        dest[k] = c;
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                // copy each source line to the appropriate place in the destination
                int pass = 1;
                int inc = 8;
                int iline = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < ih; i++) {
                        int line = i;
                        if (interlace) {
                                if (iline >= ih) {
                                        pass++;
                                        switch (pass) {
                                        case 2:
                                                iline = 4;
                                                break;
                                        case 3:
                                                iline = 2;
                                                inc = 4;
                                                break;
                                        case 4:
                                                iline = 1;
                                                inc = 2;
                                                break;
                                        default:
                                                break;
                                        }
                                }
                                line = iline;
                                iline += inc;
                        }
                        line += iy;
                        if (line < height) {
                                int k = line * width;
                                int dx = k + ix; // start of line in dest
                                int dlim = dx + iw; // end of dest line
                                if ((k + width) < dlim) {
                                        dlim = k + width; // past dest edge
                                }
                                int sx = i * iw; // start of line in source
                                while (dx < dlim) {
                                        // map color and insert in destination
                                        int index = ((int) pixels[sx++]) & 0xff;
                                        int c = act[index];
                                        if (c != 0) {
                                                dest[dx] = c;
                                        }
                                        dx++;
                                }
                        }
                }
                image = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest, width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
        }

        public Bitmap getFrame(int n) {
                if (frameCount <= 0)
                        return null;
                n = n % frameCount;
                return ((GifFrame) frames.elementAt(n)).image;
        }

        public int read(InputStream is) {
                init();
                if (is != null) {
                        in = is;
                        readHeader();
                        if (!err()) {
                                readContents();
                                if (frameCount < 0) {
                                        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                                }
                        }
                } else {
                        status = STATUS_OPEN_ERROR;
                }
                try {
                        is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return status;
        }

        protected void decodeBitmapData() {
                int nullCode = -1;
                int npix = iw * ih;
                int available, clear, code_mask, code_size, end_of_information, in_code, old_code, bits, code, count, i, datum, data_size, first, top, bi, pi;
                if ((pixels == null) || (pixels.length < npix)) {
                        pixels = new byte[npix]; // allocate new pixel array
                }
                if (prefix == null) {
                        prefix = new short[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
                }
                if (suffix == null) {
                        suffix = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
                }
                if (pixelStack == null) {
                        pixelStack = new byte[MAX_STACK_SIZE + 1];
                }
                // Initialize GIF data stream decoder.
                data_size = read();
                clear = 1 << data_size;
                end_of_information = clear + 1;
                available = clear + 2;
                old_code = nullCode;
                code_size = data_size + 1;
                code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                for (code = 0; code < clear; code++) {
                        prefix[code] = 0; // XXX ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                        suffix[code] = (byte) code;
                }
                // Decode GIF pixel stream.
                datum = bits = count = first = top = pi = bi = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < npix;) {
                        if (top == 0) {
                                if (bits < code_size) {
                                        // Load bytes until there are enough bits for a code.
                                        if (count == 0) {
                                                // Read a new data block.
                                                count = readBlock();
                                                if (count <= 0) {
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                                bi = 0;
                                        }
                                        datum += (((int) block[bi]) & 0xff) << bits;
                                        bits += 8;
                                        bi++;
                                        count--;
                                        continue;
                                }
                                // Get the next code.
                                code = datum & code_mask;
                                datum >>= code_size;
                                bits -= code_size;
                                // Interpret the code
                                if ((code > available) || (code == end_of_information)) {
                                        break;
                                }
                                if (code == clear) {
                                        // Reset decoder.
                                        code_size = data_size + 1;
                                        code_mask = (1 << code_size) - 1;
                                        available = clear + 2;
                                        old_code = nullCode;
                                        continue;
                                }
                                if (old_code == nullCode) {
                                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                        old_code = code;
                                        first = code;
                                        continue;
                                }
                                in_code = code;
                                if (code == available) {
                                        pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                                        code = old_code;
                                }
                                while (code > clear) {
                                        pixelStack[top++] = suffix[code];
                                        code = prefix[code];
                                }
                                first = ((int) suffix[code]) & 0xff;
                                // Add a new string to the string table,
                                if (available >= MAX_STACK_SIZE) {
                                        break;
                                }
                                pixelStack[top++] = (byte) first;
                                prefix[available] = (short) old_code;
                                suffix[available] = (byte) first;
                                available++;
                                if (((available & code_mask) == 0) && (available < MAX_STACK_SIZE)) {
                                        code_size++;
                                        code_mask += available;
                                }
                                old_code = in_code;
                        }
                        // Pop a pixel off the pixel stack.
                        top--;
                        pixels[pi++] = pixelStack[top];
                        i++;
                }
                for (i = pi; i < npix; i++) {
                        pixels[i] = 0; // clear missing pixels
                }
        }
        protected boolean err() {
                return status != STATUS_OK;
        }
        protected void init() {
                status = STATUS_OK;
                frameCount = 0;
                frames = new Vector<GifFrame>();
                gct = null;
                lct = null;
        }

        protected int read() {
                int curByte = 0;
                try {
                        curByte = in.read();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                }
                return curByte;
        }

        protected int readBlock() {
                blockSize = read();
                int n = 0;
                if (blockSize > 0) {
                        try {
                                int count = 0;
                                while (n < blockSize) {
                                        count = in.read(block, n, blockSize - n);
                                        if (count == -1) {
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        n += count;
                                }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (n < blockSize) {
                                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                        }
                }
                return n;
        }

        protected int[] readColorTable(int ncolors) {
                int nbytes = 3 * ncolors;
                int[] tab = null;
                byte[] c = new byte[nbytes];
                int n = 0;
                try {
                        n = in.read(c);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (n < nbytes) {
                        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                } else {
                        tab = new int[256]; // max size to avoid bounds checks
                        int i = 0;
                        int j = 0;
                        while (i < ncolors) {
                                int r = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                                int g = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                                int b = ((int) c[j++]) & 0xff;
                                tab[i++] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                        }
                }
                return tab;
        }

        /**
         * Main file parser. Reads GIF content blocks.
         */
        protected void readContents() {
                // read GIF file content blocks
                boolean done = false;
                while (!(done || err())) {
                        int code = read();
                        switch (code) {
                        case 0x2C: // image separator
                                readBitmap();
                                break;
                        case 0x21: // extension
                                code = read();
                                switch (code) {
                                case 0xf9: // graphics control extension
                                        readGraphicControlExt();
                                        break;
                                case 0xff: // application extension
                                        readBlock();
                                        String app = "";
                                        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                                                app += (char) block[i];
                                        }
                                        if (app.equals("NETSCAPE2.0")) {
                                                readNetscapeExt();
                                        } else {
                                                skip(); // don't care
                                        }
                                        break;
                                case 0xfe:// comment extension
                                        skip();
                                        break;
                                case 0x01:// plain text extension
                                        skip();
                                        break;
                                default: // uninteresting extension
                                        skip();
                                }
                                break;
                        case 0x3b: // terminator
                                done = true;
                                break;
                        case 0x00: // bad byte, but keep going and see what happens break;
                        default:
                                status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                        }
                }
        }


        protected void readGraphicControlExt() {
                read(); // block size
                int packed = read(); // packed fields
                dispose = (packed & 0x1c) >> 2; // disposal method
                if (dispose == 0) {
                        dispose = 1; // elect to keep old image if discretionary
                }
                transparency = (packed & 1) != 0;
                delay = readShort() * 10; // delay in milliseconds
                transIndex = read(); // transparent color index
                read(); // block terminator
        }

        protected void readHeader() {
                String id = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        id += (char) read();
                }
                if (!id.startsWith("GIF")) {
                        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR;
                        return;
                }
                readLSD();
                if (gctFlag && !err()) {
                        gct = readColorTable(gctSize);
                        bgColor = gct[bgIndex];
                }
        }
        protected void readBitmap() {
                ix = readShort(); // (sub)image position & size
                iy = readShort();
                iw = readShort();
                ih = readShort();
                int packed = read();
                lctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 - local color table flag interlace
                lctSize = (int) Math.pow(2, (packed & 0x07) + 1);
                interlace = (packed & 0x40) != 0;
                if (lctFlag) {
                        lct = readColorTable(lctSize); // read table
                        act = lct; // make local table active
                } else {
                        act = gct; // make global table active
                        if (bgIndex == transIndex) {
                                bgColor = 0;
                        }
                }
                int save = 0;
                if (transparency) {
                        save = act[transIndex];
                        act[transIndex] = 0; // set transparent color if specified
                }
                if (act == null) {
                        status = STATUS_FORMAT_ERROR; // no color table defined
                }
                if (err()) {
                        return;
                }
                decodeBitmapData(); // decode pixel data
                skip();
                if (err()) {
                        return;
                }
                frameCount++;
                image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_4444);
                setPixels(); // transfer pixel data to image
                frames.addElement(new GifFrame(image, delay)); // add image to frame
                if (transparency) {
                        act[transIndex] = save;
                }
                resetFrame();
        }

        protected void readLSD() {
                // logical screen size
                width = readShort();
                height = readShort();
                // packed fields
                int packed = read();
                gctFlag = (packed & 0x80) != 0; // 1 : global color table flag
                // 2-4 : color resolution
                // 5 : gct sort flag
                gctSize = 2 << (packed & 7); // 6-8 : gct size
                bgIndex = read(); // background color index
                pixelAspect = read(); // pixel aspect ratio
        }

        protected void readNetscapeExt() {
                do {
                        readBlock();
                        if (block[0] == 1) {
                                int b1 = ((int) block[1]) & 0xff;
                                int b2 = ((int) block[2]) & 0xff;
                                loopCount = (b2 << 8) | b1;
                        }
                } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
        }
        protected int readShort() {
                // read 16-bit value, LSB first
                return read() | (read() << 8);
        }
        protected void resetFrame() {
                lastDispose = dispose;
                lrx = ix;
                lry = iy;
                lrw = iw;
                lrh = ih;
                lastBitmap = image;
                lastBgColor = bgColor;
                dispose = 0;
                transparency = false;
                delay = 0;
                lct = null;
        }
        protected void skip() {
                do {
                        readBlock();
                } while ((blockSize > 0) && !err());
        }
}





public class GifDecoderView extends ImageView {
    private boolean mIsPlayingGif = false;
    private GifDecoder mGifDecoder;
    private Bitmap mTmpBitmap;
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mTmpBitmap != null && !mTmpBitmap.isRecycled()) {
                GifDecoderView.this.setImageBitmap(mTmpBitmap);
            }
        }
    };
    public GifDecoderView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
        super(context);
        playGif(stream);
    }
    public  void playGif(InputStream stream) {
        mGifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
        mGifDecoder.read(stream);
        mIsPlayingGif = true;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final int n = mGifDecoder.getFrameCount();
                final int ntimes = mGifDecoder.getLoopCount();
                int repetitionCounter = 0;
                do {
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        mTmpBitmap = mGifDecoder.getFrame(i);
                        int t = mGifDecoder.getDelay(i);
                        mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(t);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    if(ntimes != 0) {
                        repetitionCounter ++;
                    }
                } while (mIsPlayingGif && (repetitionCounter <= ntimes));
            }
        }).start();
    }
    public void stopRendering() {
        mIsPlayingGif = true;
    }
}
```

This is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gif_main);
            playGif("animation2.gif");
        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }
    public void playGif(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(name);
            GifDecoderView gif= new GifDecoderView(getApplicationContext(), is);

            LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
            ll.removeAllViews();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
            ll.addView(gif, is), params);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btn1:
            playGif("animation2.gif");
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            playGif("animation1.gif");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Please check this code. Thanks in advance. App getting crashed when I continuously swaping the image.

Comment: please show us the logcat output

Comment: Since this GIF is baked into your app, you might consider just converting it to an `AnimationDrawable`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/01/converting-animated-gifs-animationdrawables.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the GarbageCollector not having released the old GIF Instances as you recreate them all the time, over and over again!

Try caching both GifDecoderView instances, i.e. create them once and keep them during runtime,  instead of recreating them, i.e. in your oncreate do this:

```
InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(gif0Name);
this.mGif0 = new GifDecoderView(getApplicationContext(), is);
is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(gif1Name);
this.mGif1 = new GifDecoderView(getApplicationContext(), is);
```

Add the two field s in the class accordingly and remember to destroy them once your activity will be destroyed.

Also: Consider not to recreate the entire views but to stop playback of the gif to be hidden and hide the enclosing view! WIll make your code much smaller and you don't have to recreate stuff all the time!

**EDIT:** By the way, what does your DecoderView do, if you add this GIFMovieView?

Comment: one more question If I have 20 or 30 gif file. Should I upload all of them on oncreate()..

Comment: Most likely you'll run into OutOfMemory Errors over and over again using that huge amount of GIFs i guess. Consuming a lot of memory, not even caching might help on some devices! The basic principle to optimize this however is to create a local cache that maps GifObjects by String (Filename->Object) and to create and cache them on demand. This will decrease memory consumption to the minimum and only keep data in memory that is required.